# control insertion to BST according to user inputs

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is my code for binary search tree:

```
      #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

node* createNode(int value) 
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
node* insert( node* root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL) return createNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);

    return root;
}

void inorder(node* root) 
{

    inorder(root->left);
    cout<< root->data<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);
}


int main()
{
    node *root = NULL;
    int n;
    cout << "How many values do you want to enter" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int no;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> no;
        insert(root, no);
    }


    inorder(root);
}
```

When I call display function/inorder in int main() it displays no values and the program stops with error
I am using loop to take input so it can take values upto to user specified value/range
but the display/inorder function is not working.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: In `main`, `insert(root, no);` should be `root = insert(root, no);`.

Comment: yes i just did that but it is still giving me error

Answer (score 2):

In inOrder function you don't have stop condition!
and in the main should be `root=insert(root, no);`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;

node* createNode(int value) 
{
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
node* insert( node* root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL) return createNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);

    return root;
}

void inorder(node* root) 
{
    if(root == NULL)return;
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<< root->data<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);
}


int main()
{
    node *root = NULL;
    int n;
    cout << "How many values do you want to enter" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int no;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> no;
        root=insert(root, no);
    }


    inorder(root);
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply thanks i understand the problem now

Comment: if my answer helped you, vote up  my answer please.